# How to add this specific condition to my SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, filter, sum

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following T-SQL query that runs fine and gives the following output:

```
SELECT a.StayID,           
       a.StayDate,      
       a.PlanCode,
       c.[Currency],
       a.Rate,
       d.[ROE],    
       c.[Property],
       c.[Tour]        

FROM ResStay a    

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT *

FROM [LIST]) c ON c.[StayID] = a.StayID and c.[MTH] = datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar)

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT *

FROM [PKGREVENUE]) d ON d.[StayID] = a.StayID AND d.[StayDate] = a.StayDate

WHERE c.[Status] <> 'CANCELED'

AND a.[StayDate] >= '2015-07-01'   

ORDER BY a.StayID, a.StayDate
```

Current output is as follows:

```
StayID  StayDate    PlanCode    Cuurency    Rate    ROE  Property   Tour
 152    2015-07-01   G1HB        GBP        102     56     ASD      Smith
 152    2015-07-02  G1HB         GBP        102     56     ASD      Smith
 152    2015-07-03  G1HB         GBP        102     56     ASD      Smith
 178    2015-09-11  COAI         GBP         0      48     ASD      Jones
 178    2015-09-12  DEAI         GBP        115     48     ASD      Jones
 189    2015-10-02  COHB         GBP         0      56     ASD      Thomson
 189    2015-10-03  COHB         GBP         0      56     ASD      Thomson
 189    2015-10-04  COHB         GBP         0      56     ASD      Thomson
```

I need to add a filter to my query so that it excludes all StayID whose SUM of Rate equals 0.

Thus I need to modify my query so as to have the following output:

```
StayID  StayDate    PlanCode    Cuurency    Rate    ROE  Property   Tour
 152    2015-07-01   G1HB        GBP        102     56     ASD      Smith
 152    2015-07-02   G1HB        GBP        102     56     ASD      Smith
 152    2015-07-03   G1HB        GBP        102     56     ASD      Smith
 178    2015-09-11   COAI        GBP         0      48     ASD      Jones
 178    2015-09-12   DEAI        GBP        115     48     ASD      Jones
```

Comment: where is the resid field?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up. I meant "StayID". I have modified my post.

Comment: @user3115933 Please check answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a cum_rate column and filter over it.

```
SELECT q.StayID, q.StayDate, q.PlanCode, q.Currency, q.Rate, q.ROE, q.Property, q.Tour FROM
(SELECT a.StayID,           
       a.StayDate,      
       a.PlanCode,
       c.[Currency],
       a.Rate,
       SUM(a.RATE) OVER(PARTITION BY StayID) as CUM_RATE,
       d.[ROE],    
       c.[Property],
       c.[Tour]        

FROM ResStay a    

INNER JOIN 

[LIST] c ON c.[StayID] = a.StayID and c.[MTH] = datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar)

INNER JOIN 

[PKGREVENUE] d ON d.[StayID] = a.StayID AND d.[StayDate] = a.StayDate

WHERE c.[Status] <> 'CANCELED'

AND a.[StayDate] >= '2015-07-01'   
)q
WHERE q.CUM_RATE >0
    ORDER BY q.ReservationStayID, q.StayDate
```

Comment: It doesn't let me USE the CUM_Rate as a filter. I have replaced it by " AND SUM(a.RATE) OVER(PARTITION BY StayID) > 0" but I get the following error message:
"Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses."

Comment: However it does add a column "Cum_Rate" and computes the figures correctly. Issue is at the filtering level.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

To sum your Rates, you would need to use aggregate function `SUM` and also use the `Max` function for your StayDate to get a single stayID with the sum of rates. Here is how you can do that:

```
SELECT a.StayID AS ReservationStayID
    ,max(a.StayDate)
    ,a.PlanCode
    ,c.[Currency]
    ,SUM(a.Rate) AS Rate
    ,d.[ROE]
    ,c.[Property]
    ,c.[Tour]
FROM ResStay a
INNER JOIN [LIST] c ON c.[StayID] = a.StayID
    AND c.[MTH] = datename(m, StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy, StayDate) AS VARCHAR)
INNER JOIN [PKGREVENUE] d ON d.[StayID] = a.StayID
    AND d.[StayDate] = a.StayDate
WHERE c.[Status] <> 'CANCELED'
    AND a.[StayDate] >= '2015-07-01'
GROUP BY a.stayID
    ,a.PlanCode
    ,c.Currency
    ,d.ROE
    ,c.Property
    ,c.Tour
HAVING SUM(a.Rate) > 0
ORDER BY a.StayID
```

**Note:** I removed select statement in your joins as this is not needed. You can directly join to the table without a select. So, I hope you don't mind me changing that as well.

Comment: Thanks. It does the job but it changed the output by giving only one single row for each StayID. I guess it's because of the max(StayDate).
Also, thanks for correcting the Select statements of the joins; I will take that into account.